# How to join results?

Tags: python, merge, google-colaboratory

So, I have a dataset that after processing, returns me two independent dataframe with single column, like so:

| df1 column 1 |
| --- |
| False |
| Invalid |
| False |
| False |

| df2 column 1 |
| --- |
| False |
| False |
| False |
| Not Found |

How do I combine the columns so that the results are like this:

| column 1 |
| --- |
| False |
| Invalid |
| False |
| Not Found |

I already tried merging/joining, but the results aren't what I want. This is my code and result:

```
#tried all, inner, outer, left, and right
merge = pd.merge(bounce, domain, how = 'outer', on = 'description')
merge.head(10)
```

example:

| using inner | using outer | using left | using right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | invalid | Invalid | False |
| False | invalid | False | False |
| False | False | False | False |
| False | False | False | False |

*tbh, idk why different merge is giving me different result when I only have one column

Comment: What criteria are you using to decide between the two lists?  That is certainly not obvious, and that's the key decider here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update the `False` values  in df1 with values from df2:

```py
# are the values strings or booleans? Convert the "False" to NaNs
df1["df1 column 1"] = df1["df1 column 1"].apply(
    lambda x: np.nan if x in {"False", False} else x
)

# are the values strings or booleans? Convert the "False" to NaNs
df2["df2 column 1"] = df2["df2 column 1"].apply(
    lambda x: np.nan if x in {"False", False} else x
)


df1["df1 column 1"].update(df2["df2 column 1"])
df1["df1 column 1"].fillna(False, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
  df1 column 1
0        False
1      Invalid
2        False
3    Not Found
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how to update and lambda function works? If from what I see, it's a iteration loop that replaces false with NaN else x (keep same value?). And how does the update work? does it just overwrite the first dataframe value or does it work because the value are NaN?

Comment: @daza You can read about the `pd.Series.update` here in official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html#pandas-series-update

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to keep all values that are not `False`.

Assuming both dataframes have the same length, this should do it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if df1.loc[i, 'column 1']:
        df.loc[i, 'column 1'] = df1.loc[i, 'column 1']
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'column 1'] = df2.loc[i, 'column 1']
```

Note that if both dfs were to have a value that is not `False`, the one for df1 is going to be conserved.

If the values are all strings, use instead `if df1.loc[i, 'column 1'].!= 'False':`

### PS:

This one-liner works 10 times faster for your example :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column 1': [df1['column 1'][i] if df1['column 1'][i] else df2['column 1'][i] for i in range(len(df1))]})
```